# Building Nested Arrays Python

Tags: python, arrays

I am trying to create an array to send emails in Mailchimps API. I am following their documentation and I got the following error:

```
An exception occurred: {'status': 'error', 'code': -2, 'name': 'ValidationError', 'message': 'Validation error: {"message":{"to":["Please enter an array"]}}'}
```

So I've updated my array as follows:

```
message = {"from_email": "test1@email.com","from_name":"Test","message":{"to":["email":"test2@email.com"]}}
```

However, I'm getting an invalid syntax error under my nested array in messages and I can't quite seem to solve this. Could anyone quickly help?

Comment: Do you need the `email` key? Should that be a list of dictionaries? e.g. `[{"email":"test2@email.com"}]`, or just a list of addresses `["test2@email.com"]`?

Comment: Replace square brackets [ ] with curly { }. Or remove ```"email":``` at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you used list `[]` in place of `{}` for dictionary

```
..."message":{"to":["email":"test2@email.com"]}}
                   ^                         ^
```

change it to

```
message = {"from_email": "test1@email.com","from_name":"Test","message":{"to":{"email":"test2@email.com"}}}
```

Answer (score -1):

As per the documentation of Mail-Chimp and as you tagged with Python, you may use their Python SDK and sending a mail is as simple as below -

```
import mailchimp_transactional as MailchimpTransactional
from mailchimp_transactional.api_client import ApiClientError

try:
  mailchimp = MailchimpTransactional.Client("YOUR_API_KEY")
  response = client.messages.send({"message": {}})
  print(response)
except ApiClientError as error:
  print("An exception occurred: {}".format(error.text))
```

For Installation, use `pip install mailchimp_transactional`